# Android - Display Polylines

Tags: android, google-maps, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have an application with two activities. In the first activity the user is able to set two markers on the map and a path will be drawn between the two markers. In the second activity I want to display all of the paths drawn in the first activity. To do this, I save the waypoints of the paths in a Firebase realtime database and retrieve the data in the second activity.

As of now the second activity only displays one path from the database. What I want to do is to display all paths that the user made in the first activity (saved in the database) in the second activity. I am assuming I have to do some kind of loop to do this. Any ideas on how to do this?

POJO class - Route:

```
public class Route {

    private ArrayList<Location> locations;

    public Route() {
    }

    public ArrayList<Location> getLocations() {
        return locations;
    }

    public void setLocations(ArrayList<Location> locations) {
        this.locations = locations;
    }
}
```

POJO class - Location:

```
public static class Location {
    private Double latitude;
    private Double longitude;

    public Location() {
    }

    public Double getLatitude() {
        return latitude;
    }

    public void setLatitude(Double latitude) {
        this.latitude = latitude;
    }

    public Double getLongitude() {
        return longitude;
    }

    public void setLongitude(Double longitude) {
        this.longitude = longitude;
    }
}
```

My Database:

[image]

How I retrieve data and add polyline to map:

```
  userRef.child(sharedPreferences.getString("school", null)).child("routes").child(sh.getString("key", null)).addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            Route route = dataSnapshot.getValue(Route.class);
            for (Location location : route.getLocations()) {
                double lat = location.getLatitude();
                double lng = location.getLongitude();
                position = new LatLng(lat, lng);
                points.add(position);
            }
        }


 PolylineOptions lineOptions = new PolylineOptions();
    for (LatLng point : points) {
        lineOptions.add(point);
    }
    lineOptions.width(12);
    lineOptions.clickable(true);
    lineOptions.color(Color.RED);
    mMap.addPolyline(lineOptions);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your current example, you're attaching a listener to a single node under `$school/routes`, so it will only retrieve that node.

If you need to retrieve all routes at once, you'll need to attach a listener to the `routes` node and iterate through the children individually. From the [documentation on working with lists of data](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/lists-of-data#listen_for_value_events):

> Attaching a ValueEventListener to a list of data will return the entire list of data as a single DataSnapshot, which you can then loop over to access individual children.

Something like this should do the job:

```
public void drawAllRoutes() {
    userRef.child(sharedPreferences.getString("school", null)).child("routes").addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            for (DataSnapshot child : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                Route route = child.getValue(Route.class);
                drawRoute(route);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {}
    });
}

public void drawRoute(Route route) {
    PolylineOptions lineOptions = new PolylineOptions();

    for (Location location : route.getLocations()) {
        double lat = location.getLatitude();
        double lng = location.getLongitude();
        lineOptions.add(new LatLng(lat, lng));
    }

    lineOptions.width(12);
    lineOptions.clickable(true);
    lineOptions.color(Color.RED);

    mMap.addPolyline(lineOptions);
}
```

The `drawAllRoutes()` method attaches a listener to the `$school/routes` node instead, which will provide you with a `DataSnapshot` of the list under that node, with each individual child node provided in `DataSnapshot#getChildren()`. You can then iterate over these children to draw each polyline separately.

I have also moved your route-drawing logic into a `drawRoute()` method, so that it can draw any instance of `Route` on the map, regardless of how this `Route` object was created.

The `drawRoute()` method makes use of the `mMap` variable - that is your `GoogleMap` instance from the view - so you can only call the `drawAllRoutes()` method once the map is ready:

```
private GoogleMap mMap;

// ...

@Override
public void onMapReady(final GoogleMap googleMap) {
    mMap = googleMap;

    // ...

    drawAllRoutes();
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I will try this.

Comment: I get this error:                                                                             NullPointerException: "Attempt to invoke virtual method 'com.google.android.gms.maps.model.Polyline com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap.addPolyline(com.google.android.gms.maps.model.PolylineOptions)' on a null object reference" on the `mMap.addPolyline(lineOptions);` line

Comment: The `mMap` variable is not initialised. You'll need to [obtain the `GoogleMap` instance from the `onMapReady()` callback](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/start#the_maps_activity_java_file) before interacting with the map. The `mMap` variable you used in your example needs to be accessible in my `drawRoute()` method (as a field or passed in). You could always add `GoogleMap mMap` as a parameter to the `drawRoute()` method and pass in your `GoogleMap` instance.

Comment: I passed `mMap`as a parameter in the `drawRoute()` method, but it is still returning the same error. https://pastebin.com/m9Vmrq6b (full fragment)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/157665/discussion-between-grimthorr-and-jdoe).

Comment: Grimthorr - I need your help with structuring my database if you have time. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47035146/android-database-structure-firebase