# Android - Database Structure (Firebase)

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have an application where I have three usertypes: "The school", "Older Students", and "Younger kids". The school makes different **routes** on a map and assigns the older students as responsible for that route. The school also places multiple **stops** on the route. The stops are places where the older students pick up the younger kids.

In my application the school usertype is able to set two markers on the map and a path will be drawn between the two markers (**route**). I want to save the LatLng of both markers as they indicate the start and end of the route. I also want to save the address of both markers. I use geocoder to get the address of the routes.

The school is also able to add just one marker at a time(**stops**). When the marker is placed the user is prompted to enter the address of the marker and the time of which the older students should pick up the younger kids. I want to save the LatLng, address of the marker and the entered time.

The school should be able to see the routes created in a listview where the start-address, end-address, stops-addresses with the time is displayed. When clicking on the routes in the listview there should be shown a list of all older students where the school can assign the older students as responsible for the route.

The older students be able to see the route and the stops they are assigned to.

The younger kids should be able to see just the **stops**. By clicking on the marker on the map they indicate that they want to get picked up at that stop.

As of now the structure of my firebase database is:

```
School Name
   users
     userID
       username 
       usertype
   markers
     uniqueID
       latitude
       longitude
       address
       time
   routes
     uniqueID
        startAddress
        endAddress
        locations
           0
             latitude
             longitude
           1
             latitude
             longitude
```

Where the locations node is an array of waypoints of the route. This structure makes it very difficult to meet my requirements. Any ideas of a better database structure?

```
public class Route {

private ArrayList<MapFragment.Location> locations;

private String startDestination;
private String endDestination;
HashMap<String, Boolean> markerId;


public Route() {
}

public Route(ArrayList<MapFragment.Location> locations, String startDestination, String endDestination, HashMap<String, Boolean> markerId) {
    this.locations = locations;
    this.startDestination = startDestination;
    this.endDestination = endDestination;
    this.markerId = markerId;
}

public String getStartDestination() {
    return startDestination;
}

public void setStartDestination(String startDestination) {
    this.startDestination = startDestination;
}

public String getEndDestination() {
    return endDestination;
}

public void setEndDestination(String endDestination) {
    this.endDestination = endDestination;
}


public ArrayList<MapFragment.Location> getLocations() {
    return locations;
}

public void setLocations(ArrayList<MapFragment.Location> locations) {
    this.locations = locations;
}


}
```

[image]

Comment: Could you elaborate on how the current structure (which is mostly denormalized) makes it difficult to meet your requirements?

Comment: Because the routes and markers are in different nodes with different uniqueIDs it is impossible to know which makrers (stops) are connected to which routes. So if a older student is assigned to a route, that older student has no idea of which markers are on the specific route.

Comment: Idea: Wouldn't it be a better solution to put the markers node inside the routes node?. So it would be `routes/uniqueID/markers`

Comment: Do you have any ideas? Or should I just stick with my original structure

Comment: I think you need to start using IDs as indexes to fan out your data, as described under the [create data that scales documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/structure-data#fanout). I'll compose an answer shortly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like the relationships between these objects could be summarized as:

- A school contains many routes, markers and users
- A route has a [one-to-many relationship](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One-to-many_(data_model)) with markers
- A marker has a [one-to-one relationship](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One-to-one_(data_model)) with a route
- A user has a one-to-many relationship with markers and routes

As we know, the Firebase Realtime Database is a NoSQL database and therefore doesn't explicitly support relationships, but they can be inferred in the structure, so take this structure for example (where `...` is your existing values):

```
schoolId
  users
    userId
      ...
  markers
    markerId
      ...
      route      // the route ID that this marker belongs to
  routes
    routeId
      ...
      markers    // list of marker IDs that belong to this route
```

> **Note**: To keep this example simple, I'll ignore the `users` relationships for now and just work with the relationships between `markers` and `routes`.

With this structure: whether we are currently working with a marker or a route, we can easily find out how they relate to each other.

It is then easy to get all markers related to a specific route by [performing a query](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/lists-of-data#filtering_data) against the `route` value of children in the markers node:

```
schoolReference.child("markers").orderByChild("route").equalTo(routeId);
```

Where `routeId` is the unique ID of the route we are currently working with.

You'll need to be aware of some changes when creating objects though, so for example, when you create a marker with this structure, you'll need to:

- Set the `route` value of the marker to the the ID of the route that it belongs to, and
- add the marker ID to the `markers` list under the route that it belongs to.

You can achieve this in one write operation using a [transaction](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/read-and-write#save_data_as_transactions) or a [multi-location update](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/read-and-write#update_specific_fields).

> **Note**: You don't actually have to use the `routeId/markers` list, but it can be useful if you're using [FirebaseUI to display indexed data](https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android/blob/master/database/README.md#using-firebaseui-with-indexed-data).

This technique of using IDs as index keys is called data fan out and you can read more about it in the [structure your database documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/structure-data#fanout).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Regarding the routeId and the markerId, do they come from the `push()` method?

Comment: That's correct, you can use `push()` to generate a unique ID for each new object.

Comment: As of now I can make multiple markers on the map, but when I click my "save route and markers" button, it only takes the last marker I put on the map and saves it. Are there a way of inserting all markers with seperate makerId's?

Comment: You'll need to use `push()` to create a new unique ID for each new object you want to store in the database. This might be better as a separate question though as we may need to see your code for that button.

Comment: Yes I agree. I got the first part to work. So I now insert the routeId in the markers node for one marker only. The new thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47039831/android-inserting-multiple-markers-using-push

Comment: Regarding saving the marker IDs under the route node: Should they be saved as a list?

Comment: Yes, as an index list - so effectively a `HashMap<String, Boolean>` like `markerId: true`. See the [data fan out example](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/structure-data#fanout) which uses `"techpioneers": true` under the `groups` child (where `"techpioneers"` is the key of a group).

Comment: I have updated my original post. I have added a hashmap of `markerId`, to my route model class. Could I then make a new instance of that class in my activity and then use a hashmap and the updateChildren method to insert to the database?

Comment: Yes, that should work. If you store the `Route` instance into the database directly, Firebase will automatically convert a `HashMap` to `key: value` pairs.

Comment: This works :) Now to query all routes with the markers, I would like to use FirebaseUI as you explained. The keyQuery would be the `marker` node and the databaseReference would be the `routes` node. Am I right?

Comment: My adapter returns empty when I do this.

Comment: The `keyQuery` should be the specific `/routes/routeId/markers` node and the `dataRef` should be the `/markers` root node.

Comment: What if I wanted to get all routes, so each index in my recyclerview consisted of: The start and end addresses of the route and all the markers that belongs to that route. So each row shows **one route** the attributes of that route and the markers associated with that route. Is that possible to query? I have updated my post to show the database.

Comment: You would need to start adding (duplicating) marker data under the route node so that your bind method in the RecyclerView would have some details about the markers without having to actually query the markers node. For example you could add a `markerNames` node to the each route that linked marker IDs to marker names as a map. If you need some example code, feel free to post another question.

Comment: I have posted a new question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47094253/android-querying-data-from-firebase