# Android - Inserting multiple markers using push()

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am able to insert multiple markers on my map. But when I am inserting to my Firebase database, it is only the last marker placed that get inserted. I am thinking I have to use somekind of list or hashmap.

POJO class:

```
public class FirebaseMarker {

  String address;
  String time;
  double latitude;
  double longitude;
  String routeId;

  public FirebaseMarker() {
  }

  public FirebaseMarker(String address, String time, double latitude, double longitude, String routerId) {
      this.address = address;
      this.time = time;
      this.latitude = latitude;
      this.longitude = longitude;
      this.routeId = routerId;
  }

  public String getRouterId() {
    return routeId;
  }

  public void setRouterId(String routerId) {
    this.routeId = routerId;
  }

  public String getAddress() {
    return address;
  }

  public void setAddress(String address) {
    this.address = address;
  }

  public String getTime() {
    return time;
  }

  public void setTime(String time) {
    this.time = time;
  }

  public double getLatitude() {
    return latitude;
  }

  public void setLatitude(double latitude) {
    this.latitude = latitude;
  }

  public double getLongitude() {
    return longitude;
  }

  public void setLongitude(double longitude) {
    this.longitude = longitude;
  }
}
```

Marker creation:

```
List<Marker> markers;
markers = new ArrayList<>();

Marker marker =  mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                 .position(latLng)
                 .title(address)
                 .snppet(time)
                 .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_RED)));

 markers.add(marker);
```

How I am inserting:

```
//FirebaseMarker marker = new FirebaseMarker(address, time, latitude, longitude, routeId); 

 markerId = userRef.push().getKey();
userRef.child(sharedPreferences.getString("school",null)).child("markers").child(markerId).setValue(markers);
```

The parameters are both from userinput and from geo-coder

[image]

Comment: Can you share the code that adds the marker to the map? I think you'll need to add this marker to a `List` or `HashMap` when it's created, and then save that list to the database when the button is pressed.

Comment: I have edited my post. I have a list where I add my markers and I insert the list in my database. Would this work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you have the general premise of saving the marker to the database correct, but you'll need to store each marker in memory first to be able to save them to the database later.

For this, you can use a `HashMap` to simplify saving:

```
HashMap<String, Object> markers = new HashMap<>();

public void createMarker(String routeId, LatLng latLng, String address, String time) {    
    // Create a unique ID for this marker (but don't actually store it yet)
    String markerId = schoolReference.child("markers").push().getKey();

    // Add the marker to the HashMap
    FirebaseMarker marker = new FirebaseMarker(address, time, latLng.getLatitude(), latLng.getLongitude(), routeId);
    markers.put(markerId, marker);

    // Add an actual map marker to the map
    mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
        .position(latLng)
        .title(address)
        .snppet(time)
        .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_RED))
    );
}
```

In this example, when you create the marker (in the `createMarker()` method), you perform 3 additional actions before actually adding a marker to the map:

- Generate a unique ID for this marker, using `push()` (this does not contact the database)
- Create a `FirebaseMarker` instance that can be used later
- Add this unique ID and `FirebaseMarker` pair to a `HashMap`

Then, when you want to save these to the database, you simply push the entire `HashMap` onto the database by [performing a multi-location update using `updateChildren()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/read-and-write#update_specific_fields):

```
public void saveToDatabase() {
    // Do your thing to save the route

    // Save the markers to the database in one write operation
    schoolReference.child("markers").updateChildren(markers);
}
```

Comment: I've just noticed that this is similar to the revised answer that @AlexMamo has posted, so both should work.

Comment: I'll try to do this.

Comment: Quick question: When you write schoolReference, do you mean as a databaseReference or the actual school variable i have saved inside sharedPreferences?

Comment: Sorry `schoolReference` is the database reference to your "Some School Name" node.

Comment: This works. The mistake I made with the answer that @AlexMamo gave was the line  `String markerId = schoolReference.child("markers").push().getKey();` was placed i the onCreatedView method.

Answer (score 1):

To solve this, you need to have a unique identifier for each insertion. Because a Firebase database is a NoSQL database and is structured as pairs of key and values, every node is a `Map`, which means in the case of `Map`, it replaces the old value with the new one. So, you need to change this line of code:

```
userRef.child(sharedPreferences.getString("school",null)).child("markers").child(markerId).setValue(marker);
```

with

```
userRef.push().child(sharedPreferences.getString("school",null)).child("markers").child(markerId).setValue(marker);
```

As you probably see, i have added the `push()` method right after your `userRef`. If you need to have that pushed key in another location, just move that method in the right position.

**Edit:** To update a node in your Firebase database you need to use `updateChildren()` method in stead of `setValue()` like this:

```
markerId = userRef.push().getKey();
Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<>();
map.put(markerId, marker);
userRef.child(sharedPreferences.getString("school",null)).child("markers").updateChildren(map);
```

Comment: This is not exactly how I wanted it. The markerId child is a push(). I have edited my code. The problem is that when I have for example 3 markers in my map. When I press my save button only the last marker is saved.

Comment: The `markerId` child wasn't present in you code earlier. So please see my updated answer.

Comment: I don't want to updateChildren. If I have 3 markers in my map, I want to insert three new nodes with push().

Comment: Apologies for implementing your code the wrong way. My mistake. Your code works fine

Comment: Happy to hear that. If you think that my answer helped you, please consider accepting it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```
FirebaseMarker marker = new FirebaseMarker(address, time, latitude, 
longitude, routeId); 

DatabaseReference userRef=FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("sharedPreferences.getString("school",null)").child("markers").push().setValue(marker);
```

Comment: This adds one node at the root, instead of inside the school node. But it still only adds one node

Comment: I tried. It does not work. I have edited my post with a picture of my database. Only one push() id is added.

Comment: The "Some School Name" child and "sharedPreferences.getString("school",null) child is the same thing

Comment: @JDoe okay I updated it, this should generate a random id for each marker

Comment: It still does the same

Comment: There is a problem in the code not firebase, if you change the code and make it when you add a marker it will be sent to the database it will work. But you are clicking save and then sending to database it will only take the last one

Comment: Yes, that must be the problem. Are there a way of adding the markers to a list of somekind and then sending them to firebase?

Comment: I would put them in a listview, when a user creates a marker it will be as an item in a listview and sent to the database, when he creates another one also same process..You can add marker in dialog (with save button in dialog) then send it to database and put it as as item in the activity

Comment: Yes, but I don't think it will work like that, as I am also saving the route when the save button is pressed. But thanks for your help.