# Android - Querying data from Firebase

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have data in my Firebase realtime database that I want to query and show in my Recyclerview, but I am confused on how to do this.

Database Structure:

[image]

For **one activity** I want to query only the markers node. **This seems easy to do with FirebaseUI**

For **another activity** I want to query all routes and all markers. So **each row in my recyclerview consist of:** startDestination and endDestination of one route, the addresses and times of the markers connected to that route

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is somewhat a follow on from my previous answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47038385/2754146) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47054119/2754146), so I'll do my best to provide some examples for you.

### Create data that scales

The basic premise here is that you want to try to avoid downloading all the data associated with the route's markers when displaying a list of routes. This is because you won't need to know everything about the markers at this point, only partial details.

Furthermore, the less data you download from the database (across the network) to display a list of routes, the quicker this list can be composed. Imagine, for instance, that you have 1000 routes and each route has 10 markers; this would mean downloading 1000 routes and 10000 markers just to display a list of routes.

This is why the [documentation suggests using data fanout](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/structure-data#fanout) to create data that scales and it's also recommended to [denormalize](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Denormalization) and duplicate data in NoSQL databases.

### Data duplication

So, in order to quickly and easily obtain a useable list of markers associated with a specific route, you'll want to start storing marker addresses and times on the route node, like you have done with marker IDs.

One possible solution to this would be to create an additional `PartialMarker` class that holds limited information about a marker for use on the route list:

```
public class PartialMarker {
    private String address;
    private String time;

    public PartialMarker() {}

    public PartialMarker(String address, String time) {
        this.address = address;
        this.time = time;
    }

    public String getAddress() { return address; }

    public String getTime() { return time; }
}
```

And then have a `Map` of these under your `Route` class:

```
public Route {
    // ...

    private HashMap<String, PartialMarker> partialMarkers = new HashMap<>();

    public HashMap<String, PartialMarker> getPartialMarkers() { return partialMarkers; }
}
```

So that when you save a new marker to the database for a route, you'll also create a `PartialMarker` instance for each marker and save this to the route node, something like:

```
public void saveToDatabase() {
    // Do your thing to save the route

    // Create some partial markers
    HashMap<String, Object> partialMarkers = new HashMap<>();
    for (Map.Entry<String, Object> entry : markers.entrySet()) {
        String key = entry.getKey();
        FirebaseMarker marker = (FirebaseMarker) entry.getValue();
        partialMarkers.put(key, new PartialMarker(marker.getAddress(), marker.getTime()));
    }

    // Store the partial markers under the route
    schoolReference.child("routes").child(routeId).child("partialMarkers").updateChildren(partialMarkers);
}
```

Then, when you bind your `Route` to a `ViewHolder` in the `RecyclerView`, you can iterate over each `PartialMarker` to show a list of them on that row:

```
for (PartialMarker partialMarker : model.getPartialMarkers().values()) {
    // ...
}
```

### Conclusion

You could do this any number of other ways, but I hope this gives you an insight into a possible method to achieve this with denormalized data. It's difficult to understand at first because duplicating of the data seems backwards, but this is a suggested pattern for NoSQL databases, and it makes sense when you start working with huge amounts of data.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. The `partialMarkers.push` is that a hashmap reference, as no push method is available for partialMarkers? I am assuming you mean `put`

Comment: Oops sorry, yes that should be `put()` to add to the `Map`, I'm confusing maps and references!

Comment: I think it almost works. I have made it to the last part with querying, but I get an exception: `NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.util.Collection java.util.HashMap.values()' on a null object reference`. I get this error on line 87` of this pastebin: https://pastebin.com/ZsPGJNrz

Comment: This could be because not all routes have a `partialMarkers` value in the database, so you may wish to initialise the `HashMap` in the `Route` class to avoid this error, see my edit.

Comment: One small problem though. When I add for example 5 markers to the map, the partialMarkers node only shows 4. When I add 3 markers there is only 2 children under the partialMarkers node. It is always missing one.

Comment: I know it has been a while, but do you have any idea why the `partialMarkers` node is missing one marker in the database, every time?

Comment: @JDoe I'm not sure what could be causing that, but it might be worth creating a new question so you can share your current structure and code, and I'll take a look.

Comment: Okay, I have created new question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47414897/android-firebase-not-inserting-correctly