# Android - Firebase not inserting correctly

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have an application where I use a Google Maps `MapView`. With my map, I can insert markers which I save to the Firebase Realtime database. I have a `FirebaseMarker` class:

```
public class FirebaseMarker {
    String address;
    String time;
    double latitude;
    double longitude;
    ...
}
```

In my fragment, I have a `HashMap`, where I put push-keys and the markers. When a button is pressed these markers are saved to the database.

```
public class MapFragment extends Fragment implements OnMapReadyCallback {
    HashMap<String, Object> markers = new HashMap<>();

    public void onMapReady(final GoogleMap googleMap) {
        String markerIds = userRef.push().getKey();
        FirebaseMarker marker = new FirebaseMarker(address, time, latitude, longitude);
        markers.put(markerIds, marker);
    }

    private void saveToDatabase(){
        userRef.child(sharedPreferences.getString("school", null)).child("markers").updateChildren(markers);
    }
}
```

This works fine, but I also want to add the same markers with just a few properties (`PartialMarker`) inside a different node in Firebase. This gives me problems, as there is always one partial marker missing in the database. So if I put 3 markers on the map, only 2 partial markers are saved in the database inside the node. What I have done:

```
public class PartialMarker {
    String address;
    String time;
    ..
}
```

Then I do:

```
public class MapFragment extends Fragment implements OnMapReadyCallback {
    HashMap<String, Object> partialMarkers= new HashMap<>();

    public void onMapReady(final GoogleMap googleMap) {
        for (Map.Entry<String, Object> entry : markers.entrySet()) {
            String key = entry.getKey();
            FirebaseMarker marker = (FirebaseMarker) entry.getValue();
            partialMarkers.put(key, new PartialMarker(marker.getAddress(), marker.getTime()));
        }
    }

    private void saveToDatabase(){
        userRef.child(sharedPreferences.getString("school", null)).child("markers").updateChildren(markers);    
        userRef.child(sharedPreferences.getString("school", null)).child("routes").child(routeId).child("partialMarkers").updateChildren(partialMarkers);
    }
}
```

The markers node:

[image]

The partial markers node:

[image]

Comment: When do you use saveToDatabase()? Add your full code.

Comment: Your code looks OK, so there might be some other issue - can you share your complete code sample? As a quick test: if you create both markers at the same time, so when you do: `FirebaseMarker marker = new FirebaseMarker([...])`, also do: `PartialMarker partialMarker = new PartialMarker([...])` and put them in the different maps, there should always be the correct numbers of items in each list. It's likely that you're creating the `PartialMarker` map out of sync with the `FirebaseMarker` map.

Comment: As @Grimthorr says, most likely the partial marker map is getting out of sync. Put a breakpoint in `saveToDatabase()` and count the length of both maps. If they are indeed the same, can you try to isolate the problem in a small fragment that I can run? So something with hard-coded values that we can copy/paste into an app to test.

Comment: Here is the full code: https://pastebin.com/d2qUkAvS

Comment: @Grimthorr I tested the number of items in each HashMap using the `size` method, and the number of items in both the maps are exactly the same, every time I add a marker.

Comment: The maps does not seem to get out of sync when the markers are added. Could there be another problem?

Comment: On line 132 of your Pastebin, you are iterating over the `markers` map before you've added the new marker at line 142, so I don't think the maps are the same size. See my answer - it might be easier to create both the `Marker` and the `PartialMarker` at the same time, rather than iterating over the `markers` map each time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is likely an issue with iterating over the `markers` map before the newest `Marker` has been added to it, so the maps then don't contain the same number of items.

I'd recommend creating both markers at the same time, something like:

```
String markerId = userRef.push().getKey();

FirebaseMarker marker = new FirebaseMarker(address, time, latitude, longitude);
PartialMarker partialMarker = new PartialMarker(address, time)

markers.put(markerId, marker);
partialMarkers.put(markerId, partialMarker);
```

This way, it's guaranteed that both maps have the same number of items.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. This works perfectly. I have accepted your answer :)